# Nothing is being written to outfile

Tags: c

```
1. // Libraries
2. #include <stdio.h>
3.
4. // Function Declarations
5.
6. int getData     (FILE* inData, int* region, int* numFire, int* numAcres);
7. int writeReport (FILE* outReport, int region, int avrg, int numFire, int numAcres);
8. void calcAvrg   (int numAcres, int numFire, int* avrg);
9. 
10. int main (void)
11. {
13. // Local Declarations

14.     FILE* inData;
15.     FILE* outReport;
15. 
16.     int region;
17.     int numFire;
18.     int sumFire;
19.     int numAcres;
20.     int sumAcres;
21.     int avrg; // Average acres per fire
22. 
23. // Statements
24.     printf("Beginning fire report\n");
25.     if (!(inData = fopen ("fire_data.txt", "r")))
26.        {
27.         printf("\aError opening fire file\n");
28.         return 100;
29.        } // if open input
30. 
31.     if (!(outReport = fopen ("fire_report.txt", "w")))
32.     {
33.         printf("\aError opening fire report\n");
34.         return 102;
35.     } // if open output
36. 
37.     fprintf(outReport, "| Region | Number of Fires | Number of Acres| Average Acres per Fire |");
38.
39.    while (getData (inData, &region, &numFire, &numAcres))
40.     {
41.         calcAvrg    (numAcres, numFire, &avrg);
42.        writeReport (outReport, region, avrg, numFire, numAcres);
43. 
44.         sumFire += numFire;
45.         sumAcres += numAcres;
46.     } // while
47. 
48.     fprintf(outReport, "\n\n| Summary |\n");
49.     fprintf(outReport, "\nTotal Number of Fires:          %d", sumFire);
50.     fprintf(outReport, "\nTotal Number of Acres Burned:   %d", sumAcres);
51.
52.     fclose (inData);
53.     fclose (outReport);
54. 
55.     printf("Ending fire report\n");
56.     return 0;
57. } // main
58. 
59. // Function Definitions
60. 
61. int getData   (FILE* inData, int* region, int* numFire,
62.                int* numAcres)
63. {
64. // Local Declarations
65.     int ioResult;
66. 
67. // Statements
68.     ioResult = fscanf(inData, "%d%d%d", region, numFire, numAcres);
69.     if (ioResult == EOF)
70.         return 0;
71.     else if (ioResult != 3)
72.     {
73.         printf("\aError reading data\n");
74.         return 0;
75.     } // if
76.     else
77.        return 0;
78. } // getData
79. 
80. void calcAvrg (int numAcres, int numFire, int* avrg)
81. {
82. // Statements
83.     *avrg = (numAcres / numFire);
84.     return;
85. } // calcAvrg
86. 
87. int writeReport (FILE* outReport, int region, int avrg, int numFire, int numAcres)
88. {
89. // Statements
90.    fprintf(outReport, "%d %d %d %d\n", region, numFire, numAcres, avrg);
91.     return 0;
92. } // writeReport
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmGRL.png This is the picture of fire_data.txt

The program is supposed to read fire_data.text and create a fire report and then store it in fire_report.text. fire_report.txt should contain the region number, number of fires, number of acres, and average acres per fire.

When I run the program and open up the fire_report.txt nothing is being written to the file besides lines 37, 48, 49, and 50. I was wondering if I could get help with the writeReport function to see if that is the problem or something else.

Comment: Please, describe your program and describe what do you want to get.

Comment: See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Don't use pictures to show output or input data

Comment: Do not comment your question, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67068600/edit) it to improve it

Comment: [please remove the line numbers from your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714). Mark the lines you want to address by comments

Comment: probably your getdata is not working, try using fgets and sscanf instead to read from the file. it makes the handling of the file less sensitive if there is something unexpected in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getData function as it is written is a bit sensitive to the
contents of the file you read from. fscanf is notorious for being
hard to use. Instead, to make it more robust use
`fgets` to read a line from the file, then use `sscanf` to read the
individual values from the buffer alt. use strtok to pick out the contents.

You may also want to return 1 if it is successful, not 0 in both
cases.

```
int getData(FILE* inData, int* region, int* numFire, int* numAcres)
{
  char buffer[256]; 
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), inData) != NULL)
  {
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%d", region, numFire, numAcres) == 3)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer : assuming your indata is line by line, you don't show how it looks like so I am just guessing. If it is a series of triplets without any delimiter between them then you would have to have some other mechanism to read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

`getData()` always returns 0 causing the body of `while (getData (inData, &region, &numFire, &numAcres)) {}` to never iterate.

Review `getData()`  code.